# Passing a text value onblur to a php function on the same page and retuning a value to another text field

Tags: php, html

I am looking to improve the form, it works if I use the submit button and the $_POST(....) that is not eh problem.

I am truing to add new functionality. The text field Code (fcode) I want to pass this  value to a php funtion using the onBlur={this.codelookup}, this will look up a code in mysql db return a name field and I want this value to be add to another text field Name (fname).

I can get this to work i if  the submit button and the $_POST['reset'] syntax, but I am trying to do this on exit (onblur) from the code text filed, but no luck kind of stuck.

The function "codelookup" in the code block below is not completes as I am not sure how to do this. Rest of the code works fine no issue with that.
If you remove the "codelookup" the  php page works great no issues there.

any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: I need to stay on the same,m ajax might be an option. I have provided the  full page code here, there are no passwords or usernames, they are in an include php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <?php require ('header.php'); ?>
    <script>        
        function takemehome(){
            window.location.href = "./stock.php";           
        }
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
    <?php require ('nav.php'); ?>
    <main>
    <?php       
        if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            echo "<div class=\"adminerror\" >";
            echo "You have not logged in.<br>"; 
            echo "You need to be logged in to use this page.<br>";              
            echo "</div>";
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
                     'setTimeout(function () {',
                     'window.location.href = "./stock.php";',
                     '}, 2000);',  
                     '</script>';
            exit();
        }
    ?>
    <div class="container">
    <!-- HTML Code amd data goes on here in theis section "container" -->
        <h2> Add a new stock to the list. </h2> 
        <!-- < ? php $_PHP_SELF ? >  
            <form action="< ? php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post" width="80%, align="left">
            <form action="projec_insert.php" method="post" width="80%, align="left">
        --> 

        <?php
            include 'mysqlinit.php';
            include 'functions.php';
            $fcode =  "";
            $fcodeErr = "";

            session_start();
            if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
                $usercheck = $_SESSION['username'];             
            } else {
                $code = $name = $fullname = $qty = $brand = $cmmt = Null;
            }

            function codelookup(){
                // Create connection
                        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


                        // Check connection
                        if (!$conn) {
                            die("Connection failed: " .  mysqli_connect_error());
                        } 
                        /*else {
                            echo "Connected to db <br><br>";    
                        }*/

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `stock` where `stock`.code = ' ????? ' ORDER BY `pt_brand` ASC";
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                            // output data of each row
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                if ($brand == $row["pt_id"]) {
                                    echo "<option value=\"" . $row["pt_id"] . "\" selected=selected> " . $row["pt_brand"] . " </option>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<option value=\"" . $row["pt_id"] . "\"> " . $row["pt_brand"] . " </option>";
                                }

                            }
                        } else {

                        }


                        mysqli_close($conn);    


            }


            if(isset($_POST['reset']))
            {                       
                $code = $name = $fullname = $qty = $brand = $cmmt = Null;
            }
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $code = $_POST['fcode'];
                $name = $_POST['fname'];
                $fullname = $_POST['ffullname'];
                $qty = $_POST['fqty'];
                $brand = $_POST['fbrand'];
                $cmmt = $_POST['fcmmt'];

                $errorflag = false;

                //clean the two text fields.
                $code = checkInput($code);  
                $code = strtoupper($code);              
                if (empty($name)){
                    $name="NOT DEFINED";
                    $name = strtoupper($name);
                } else {
                    $name = checkInput($name);
                    $name = strtoupper($name);
                }               
                if (empty($cmmt)){
                    $cmmt=NULL;
                } else {
                    $cmmt = checkInput($cmmt);
                    $cmmt = strtoupper($cmmt);
                }               
                $fullname = $code . " - " . $name;  
                if ($qty == ""){
                    $qty = 0;
                } else {
                    $qty = (int)$qty;
                }
                if ($brand == ""){
                    $brand = 1;                 
                } else {
                    $brand = (int)$brand;
                }

                if (empty($code)) {
                    $fcodeErr = " <== Required field";
                    echo "<div class=\"error\" >";
                    echo "Error: Stock Code field is required to be set. <br>";                                     
                    echo "</div>";
                    //echo "<script>alert('Errors xx have occured missing fields on form.')</script>";
                    //exit();   
                } else {

                    // Create connection
                    //$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
                        echo "<div class=\"error\" >";
                        echo "Connection to DB has failed: " .  mysqli_connect_error() . "<br>";
                        echo "Details of coneection string <br>";
                        echo "Server:" . $servername  . "<br>";
                        echo "Username:" . $username  . "<br>";
                        echo "dbname:" . $dbname  . "<br>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        die("Connection to DB has failed: " .  mysqli_connect_error());
                    } else {

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                                    `stock`(
                                            `username`,
                                            `Code`, 
                                            `Name`, 
                                            `Full-Name`, 
                                            `Qty`, 
                                            `Brand`, 
                                            `Comments`
                                    )
                                    VALUES(
                                        '$usercheck', '$code',";
                                    if ($name  == "")   {
                                        $sql = $sql . "'NOT DEFINED', ";
                                        $sql = $sql . "'$code - NOT DEFINED',";
                                    } else {
                                        $sql = $sql . "'$name',";                                       
                                        $sql = $sql . "'$code - $name',";
                                    }
                                    if ($qty == "" || $qty < 1)
                                    {
                                        $sql = $sql . "0, ";
                                    } else {
                                        $sql = $sql . "$qty, ";
                                    }
                                    if ($brand == "" || $brand < 2)
                                    {
                                        $sql = $sql . " 1, ";
                                    } else {
                                        $sql = $sql . "$brand, ";
                                    }
                                    if ($cmmt == "" )
                                    {
                                        $sql = $sql . "NULL )";
                                    } else {
                                        $sql = $sql . "'$cmmt') ";
                                    }


                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        if (!result)
                        {
                            echo "<div class=\"error\" >";
                            echo "Connection to DB has failed: " .  mysqli_connect_error() . "<br>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            die("Connection to DB has failed: " .  mysqli_connect_error());
                        } else {
                            echo "<div class=\"sqlinst\" >";
                            echo "Record has been inserted.<br>";                               
                            //echo "SQL : " . $sql . "<br>";
                            echo "</div>"; 
                            $code = $name = $fullname = $qty = $brand = $cmmt = Null;
                        }
                        //$code = $name = $fullname = $qty = $brand = $cmmt = Null;;

                    }       
                } //if .. else from title field..

            } //end if isset isset($_POST['submit'])

            //close the mysql connection
            mysqli_close($conn);



        ?>
        <form method="post" id="add" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" width="80%, align="left">

            <table class="blueTableadd">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="ctr">Title</th>
                <th >Value</th>
              </tr>
              <thead>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                <span class="validx"> * Inidicates a Rrequired field </span> <br>
                <span class="validx"> Click <a href="./stock.php">here</a> to return to the projects list.</span>
                </td>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="title" >Code:</td>
                <td class="inputval"><input type="text" maxlength=50 name="fcode" id="fcode" size="45" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($code);?>" placeholder="Paint Code eg Xf-1, H123 etc..">
                    <span class="validx">*<?php echo $stockErr;?></span>
                </td>
              </tr>                 
              <tr>
                <td class="title" >Name/Color:</td>
                <td class="inputval"><input type="text" maxlength=50 name="fname" id="fname" size="45" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>" placeholder="Paint Color Name">
                </td>
              </tr>                           
              <tr>
                <td class="title" >QTY OH:</td>
                <td class="inputval"><input type="text" maxlength=50 name="fqty" id="fqty" size="45" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($qty);?>" placeholder="Quantity On Hand: Number">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="title" >Brand:</td>
                <td class="inputval">
                    <?php
                        include 'mysqlinit.php';    

                        // Create connection
                        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


                        // Check connection
                        if (!$conn) {
                            die("Connection failed: " .  mysqli_connect_error());
                        } 
                        /*else {
                            echo "Connected to db <br><br>";    
                        }*/

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `PTBrand` ORDER BY `pt_brand` ASC";
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


                        echo "<select name=\"fbrand\"  style=\"width: 348px\" >";
                        echo "<option value=\"\">-- Select a Brand -- </option>";

                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                            // output data of each row
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                if ($brand == $row["pt_id"]) {
                                    echo "<option value=\"" . $row["pt_id"] . "\" selected=selected> " . $row["pt_brand"] . " </option>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<option value=\"" . $row["pt_id"] . "\"> " . $row["pt_brand"] . " </option>";
                                }

                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "<option value=\"xxx\">-- No Brands Defined in DB -- </option>";
                        }
                        echo "</select>";

                        mysqli_close($conn);                    
                    ?>                                      
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="title" >Comments:</td>
                <td class="inputval">                   
                    <textarea name="fcmmt" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength=254 form="add"placeholder="Add your comments here."><?php echo htmlspecialchars($cmmt);?></textarea>
                </td>
              </tr>           
              </tbody>
            </table>

                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add New Record" />
                <input type="submit" name="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset" >
                <input type="button" name="return" onclick="takemehome()" class="btn btn-default" value="Return/Back" />

        </form>
        <br>
        <br>

    </div>
    </main>
    <?php require ('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do mean you want to do an `AJAX Request`? That is the correct way to gather data from the server without submitting the form.

Comment: Hi AJAX is an option I can use. BUT I don't have enough experience with ajax to be able to write a function to do that. so Any help/suggestion on how to write it  would be greatly appreciated. After doing a little more research, I come to the conclusion that I can't use PHP to do this, and hence ajax is the option i need to go for.

Comment: Can this be done  "onblur" exiting of the field and not on form submit, as more data will be entered afterwards? The returned value will need to be put into another field.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out an it is now working.
Using both ajax and php to get the functionality I needed.

```
<script>
    function getcodename(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) { 
            document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_get_stock_name.php?code=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
                    var rstr = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    rstr = rstr.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
                    /**document.getElementById("cname").innerHTML = rstr ;**/
                    document.getElementById("fname").value = rstr ;
                }
            }
          xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

    // Create connection
    //$message = "In funtion codelookup";
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    include 'mysqlinit.php';            
    // Check connection
    // get the q parameter from URL
    $code1 = "";    
    $name1 = "NOTFOUND";

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $code1 = $_GET['code'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `pcomp` where Code = '$code1'";
        //$sql1  = 'SELECT * FROM `pcomp` WHERE `Code` = "H413"';
        //echo "SQL = $sql";
        //echo "code = $code1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        //echo "result = $result1";             
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $name1 = $row["Name"];  
                $name1 = trim (  $name1, [ string $character_mask = " \t\n\r\0\x0B" ]         
) 
        }
        } else {
            $name1 = "NOTFOUND";
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);    
        if (empty($name1)){
            $name1 = "NOTFOUND";
        }
    } else {
        $name1 = "NOTFOUND";
    } 

    echo $name1;        

?>
```